# Center Aligning an image in a header in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am currently experimenting in WordPress an am using the theme Encounter Lite.  I have an image within the header that was Center aligned and now for some reason it isn't.  I have tried different code in the style.css sheet like float: center; but that hasn't made any difference.

I am using the current WordPress application (4.7.5).

Does anyone have a solution or suggestion to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`center` is not a valid attribute of the `float` property.

I'm not familiar with the Encounter Lite theme, but `text-align: center` applied to the `header` element may work.

Specifying the width of the image and setting the left- and right- margins to `auto` is another option. In this case, make sure the image is a block-level element: `display:block`

Comment: Thank you I'll give that a try.  Is there somewhere specific I should enter this code in the style.css sheet?  I have been trialling code within the 'header' area.